# How can i replace a word in a list of list in java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List of List, something like this:

```
List<String> message1 = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "a", "text");
List<String> message2 = Arrays.asList("this", "", "a", "");
List<String> message3 = Arrays.asList("", "is", "", "a", "text");
List<List<String>> allList = Arrays.asList(message1 , message2 , message3 );
```

In my exercise, i have to recover ther original message with the help of all the message. If the word is missing, it will be shown as "".

If the word is missed in all message, i want to replace it with something like "lost-word".
For example:

```
List<String> message1 = Arrays.asList("this", "is", "a", "");
List<String> message2 = Arrays.asList("this", "", "a", "");
List<String> message3 = Arrays.asList("", "is", "", "a", "");
List<List<String>> allList = Arrays.asList(message1 , message2 , message3 );
```

In the example, the word text is missed in all message. In that case i want to replace in that position of the allList with the word "lost-word".

I try make something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < message1.size(); i++){
    if(allList.stream().allMatch(m -> m.get(i).equals(""))) {
        allList.forEach(m -> m.set(i, "lost-word"));
    }
}
```

But i have the following error:
Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.

It seems i can use the i in tha lambda expression, what can i do to replace the missed word in all messages?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid getting error about captured variable `i` you can do the following trick:

```
for(int i = 0; i < message1.size(); i++){
    int cur = i;
    if(allList.stream().allMatch(m -> m.get(cur).equals(""))) {
        allList.forEach(m -> m.set(cur, "lost-word"));
    }
}
```

Here `cur` is effectively final (means that it doesn't change even though its not declared `final`) and we can capture it in lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access variables defined outside, from within the stream, if they are not final or effectively final.
Try something like this:

```java
IntStream.range(0, message1.size()).forEach(i -> {
    if(allList.stream().allMatch(m -> m.get(i).equals(""))) {
        allList.forEach(m -> m.set(i, "lost-word"));
    }
});
```